# Passing in new Date to d3 popups

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I have points on a map in d3, and when I hover the points, I want it to show the 'date' associated with each point.  Here's my code.

```
//Declare "Date" variable
var date

// Build new Date constructor
d3.selectAll(".events").each(function(d) {
        var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
        date = new Date(d.startDate)
        date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options)
        console.log(date) // output example: Sat Feb 23 2019, successfully iterates through every date and formats
        return date

    });

console.log(date) // output example: Sat Feb 23 2019
```

The above code works as expected.  The issue is that I can't pass in the 'date' into the below function:

```
//Reflect formatted date in popups
d3.selectAll(".events")
      .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
        console.log(date) // for every point, it shows: Sat Feb 23 2019
```

How do I pass in the formatted date from the first function, into the mouseover function?  I could put the new Date constructor inside the mouseover function but that doesn't seem right. What can I try next?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem with your code is that it's just declaring a variable...

```
var date;
```

... and overriding its value in the `each` loop:

```
d3.selectAll(".events").each(function(d) {
    date = foo;
});
```

So, at the end of the `each`, there is just **one** date variable, regardless the size of your selection.

Finally, two observations: your `return` is useless in a D3 `each`, and you can move the assignment of `options` to outside the `each` loop.

**Solutions**

1. Setting the property in the datum:

The most obvious solution is *setting* a new property for each datum in the data array, inside the `each`:

```
d3.selectAll(".events").each(function(d) {
    var date = new Date(d.startDate)
    //do your manipulation with 'date' here, then:
    d.date = date
});
```

Then you get that property using the first argument:

```
d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseover", function(d) { 
    console.log(d.date)
    //d here----^
});
```

2. Using the event listener:

However, I'd say that the most idiomatic solution is calculating the `date` directly, inside the event listener:

```
d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseover", function(d) {
    var date = new Date(d.startDate)
    //do your manipulation with 'date' here, then:
    console.log(date)
});
```

3. Using a local variable:

This is similar to solution #1, but instead of setting a new property in the datum you set a new local variable, which attaches the value to the DOM element:

```
var local = d3.local();

d3.selectAll(".events").each(function(d) {
    var date = new Date(d.startDate)
    //do your manipulation with 'date' here, then:
    local.set(this, date)
});
```

Then, you get the value with:

```
d3.selectAll(".events").on("mouseover", function(d) { 
    console.log(local.get(this))
});
```

Answer (score 0):

d3 will usually store the data in node's `__data__` property, either store it directly there or on the node itself, I'll do it on the node, `this` refers to each node:

```
d3.selectAll(".events").each(function(d) {
        var options = { weekday: 'long', year: 'numeric', month: 'long', day: 'numeric' };
        date = new Date(d.startDate)
        date.toLocaleDateString("en-US", options)
        this.__customDate = date;
    });

d3.selectAll(".events")
      .on("mouseover", function(d) { 
        console.log(this.__customDate) // for every point, it shows: Sat Feb 23 2019
```

You can remove it from the node once you are done. There are many other ways, which really don't have much of advantage over one another, pick whichever you like.